How to use Python to replicate Random Forest Regression prediction using decision paths?
I'm trying to test whether I've understood the way RandomForestRegressor produces forecast after a model's fitted. I used the California housing example to train a simple model and predict the first value in my test set. I then used apply() to obtain the nodes of all training data and the test sample of interest in each regression tree. The prediction result is 1.41307
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

X, y = datasets.fetch_california_housing(as_frame=True, return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

rf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=0)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

training_nodes = rf.apply(X_train)
test_nodes = rf.apply(X_test.iloc[[0]])

rf.predict( X_test.iloc[[0]] )
array([1.41307])


To replicate the forecast, I need to: 1. Find the nodes of my test data of interest across all regression trees 2. Find all training data that shared the same node as my test data of interest across all regression trees. 3. For each tree, calculate the average of y_train and store them. 4. Calculate the average of stored average y_train. The result I get is 1.4053, it's a large difference compared to rf.predict. Can someone please show me how I got it wrong and what are the correct steps?
matching_samples_per_tree = []

target_values_per_tree = []

for tree_idx in range(training_nodes.shape[1]):
    # Find indices where training samples fall into the same leaf as the test sample in this tree
    matching_indices = np.where(training_nodes[:, tree_idx] == test_nodes[0][tree_idx])[0]
    
    matching_samples_per_tree.append(matching_indices)
    
    # Retrieve and store the target values of these matching training samples
    target_values_per_tree.append(y_train.iloc[matching_indices].values)

means_of_each_array = []

for vals in target_values_per_tree:
    mean_value = np.mean(vals)
    means_of_each_array.append(mean_value)

np.mean(means_of_each_array) 
#1.405348333333333

